# How to make the urls and emails linkable in csv sheet using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, export-to-csv

I have written the code to download the CSV file after exporting it to CSV using nodejs.
In the CSV file there are some columns like URI and Email which I want linkable means hyperlinked after exported to CSV.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3n5kr.png)

Comment: csv files are text, if you open them in excel, I doubt it'll make text that looks like URL into a hyperlink ...

Comment: yes that is what happening right now. How to properly mae them hyperlinked then? Any idea?

Comment: I just said I doubt excel will so that, so ... the answer is "you can't do that with CSV files" - consider using a library to create an actual excel file